# How insert default columns when creating a table in PowerDesigner

Tags: powerdesigner

We have several columns that are required in all tables. Columns are used for audit, record dates, etc. What is the process for configuring PowerDesigner to automatically add these columns to the table when created in the physical model?

I am using PowerDesigner 16.5.

I have already been able to insert default triggers into DBMS Properties in Trigger Template Items, where I can insert several default triggers for all tables (although I am still learning the "language" used in PD), and in each table I will insert the default triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several ways to add design helpers to your PDM:

- Add it to the Initialize event handler of the Table class
- Create a Menu in the Table class to add them in existing tables

For all these, it is better to define these tools in a separate extension (`Tools > Resources > Extensions > Physical Data Models...`), maybe with `Auto attach`, so that it can be shared between several models. Then you can attach it to your existing model with the `Model > Extensions > Attach an Extension` toolbar item.

And you can do it in standard [VBScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/d1wf56tt(v=vs.84)), which is an actual language, and not only used in PD...

All the following elements go in this extension.

In the Global Script, the code to actually add the default columns.

```
function ColumnExists(tab, name)
   if tab.ClassName = "Table" then
      dim col
      for each col in tab.Columns
         if col.Name = name then
            ColumnExists = true
            exit function
         end if
      next 
   end if
   ColumnExists = false
end function

Sub DoCreateColumns(tab)
   if not tab.ClassName = "Table" then exit sub
   dim c
   if not ColumnExists(tab,"AuditDate") then
      set c = tab.CreateObject(cls_Column)
      c.Name = "AuditDate"
      c.Code = "ADDT"
      c.DataType = "datetime"
      output "... adding column AuditDate"
   end if
End Sub
```

On the Table class, an Event Handler for Initialize:

```
Function %Initialize%(obj)
   DoCreateColumns obj
   %Initialize% = True
End Function
```

And for the Table contextual menu, you need a Method, e.g. CreateColumns:

```
Sub %Method%(tab)
   DoCreateColumns tab
End Sub
```

and a Menu, e.g. CreateColumns (the actual contextual menu entry name is taken from the Command Caption, that you edit in the XML tab...):

```
<Menu>
   <Command Name="CreateColumns" Caption="Create Standard Columns" />
</Menu>
```